# Why can't I see the files in the project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Yesterday I created a project in Visual Studio 2022 Community using ASP.NET Core with a Razor page example. I noticed that I can't compile a given project and on the right side of the solution explorer, I don't see files from a given project. About 3 months ago, I immediately had a project with files after it was created. The same happens when I open the project already in the application or as a separate sln file. However, when I create an ASP.NET (.NET Framework) project, everything works.
[Project view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Scl.png)

I tried to reinstall Visual Studio, installed the necessary packages, tested the Repair function and even installed Visual Studio 2019. However, this also did not help. He is currently working on Windows 11. I don't know if this can affect the creation of the project.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: did you check the csproj file? can you paste it into your question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Scl.png

Comment: This is just an empty solution with no projects. You can add projects using the Add > Existing Project command

Comment: About 3 months ago, I immediately had a project with files after it was created. What could be wrong now?

Comment: Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General = Default package management format. Ensure value is: PackageReference

Comment: Error: "Yes, the value is: PackageReference. Here is the new error when i open the csproj file: "The project file could not be opened. The .NET SDK could not be located. Check that it has been installed and that the version specified in the global.json file corresponds to the installed version." https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtTL6.png"

Comment: The error message seems to tell you exactly what the issue is. Open a cmd window and type `dotnet --info`.

Comment: I know that *a picture is worth a thousand words* but this's not the case here on SO.. there are a number of good reason not to use images instead dumps of logs and or code ... please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The following message appeared in the console: .NET SDKs installed: No SDKs were found. So I installed it and still in the console it says the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided and your communication with user09938, it is preliminarily presumed that there are two dotnet paths in your environment variables.
Please follow the steps below:

1. Open the environment variable to check whether the following conditions exist:

[image]

2. If there are two or more dotnet paths, please check the correct path of your SDK
3. Delete the redundant dotnet path that does not exist
4. Open CMD and enter `dotnet --info` to see if it is normal
5. At this time, if you open the solution again, you should be able to see your project